# ¿Cómo mostrar más de 10000 registros en un UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Tengo en una base de datos de SQLite de más de 10000 registros con productos, y en una carpeta tengo las imágenes de dichos productos, solo que no puedo cargarlos todos en una `UiTableView` en Objective C.

Sé que lo que debería hacer es cargar solo los que va a ver el usuario y unos pocos más para cuando se vaya desplazando, pero no encuentro códigos de ejemplo sobre esto, y mi inglés no da para tanto.

Por ahora solo estoy cargando un límite de 1500 registros en un `NSArray`, para que la memoria del dispositivo no se sobrecargue, pero necesito poder visualizar todos los productos y que estos vayan cargando a medida que voy moviendo el *scroll* (sin tiempos de carga).

¿Alguien sabe hacer esto? ¿Qué control toca usar? ¿se usa el `NSCache` para esto?, o voy haciendo consultas cada vez que se mueve el *scroll*, no tengo muy claro cómo hacerlo, las imágenes las cargo de una carpeta del proyecto por lo cual no hay tanto problema, solo le digo al `imageview` que la cargue de ahí, con la referencia del producto.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que agregaras tu codigo, que nos mostraras tu esfuerzo, ya que SOes, no  es un sitio para buscar una opinion, sino para solucionar errores/problemas que tengas con tu codigo, despues de haberlo intentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la [Docu oficial de apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451?language=objc).

Esto se logra con `- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;`

Con esto estamos reutilizando celdas. Eso quiere decir que no vas a tener 10000 celdas en memoria sino que vas a tener solo las que son visibles para el usuario.

Un ejemplo de la docu oficial es

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"miIdentificador";

/*
 Reciclar la celda de la tabla con el identificador definido
 En este caso la celda esta definida en el storyboard
 */
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:miIdentificador];

// Aqui configurar la celda seteando la imagen e info.

return cell;
}
```

Si usas el storyboard es tan simple como configurar el reuseIdentifier
[image: reuseIdentifieren el storyvoard]
Si no estuvieras usando storyboard tendrías que registrar la celda en la tableView

```
//Aquí va el nombre del xib de mi celda este caso seria MiCelda.xib
NSString *nombreDeMiCelda = @"MiCelda";
UINib *tableCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nombreDeMiCelda bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:tableCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:miIdentificador];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.
¿Básicamente cargo los datos de la base de datos cada vez que se cargue el método dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier no?

para obtener los datos desde sqllite sería una consulta del estilo SELECT * FROM table limit indexPath.row, (indexPath.row + 1)

¿Estoy bien o ando muy perdido?

Comment: No haria la query ahi porque puede demorar(esto tiene que ser todo con datos que esten en memoria). Inicializaria el NSArray con la query, y luego en el `cellForRowAtIndex` usaria los datos de ese arreglo para setear el contenido de la celda que acabo de pedir con el `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

Comment: pues es que ya lo tengo asi, el problema es que no puedo cargar un array con 100000 registros D:, por ahora le tenemos un limite de productos por pantalla de unos 5000 pero mi jefe quiere quitar el limite XD.

¿Alguna sugerencia? gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: Lo que podes hacer es cargarlo progesivamente. Ya de por si tener una tabla que muestre 100k registros sin ningun tipo de busqueda es algo medio excesivo. Pero lo que podes hacer es hacer una carga progresiva. Al inicio cargas 5k registros en el array cuando llegas al final de esos registros pones una celda con un porgress indicator mientras se resuelve la query de los siguientes 5k (hasta ahora tenes 10k registros en el array). cuando llegas al final de esos nuevos 5k podes destruir los primeros 5k y cargar estos nuevos 5k(podes ver como en un array de 10k vas ciclando por los 100k)

Comment: Tambien podes anticiparte a que estas llegando al final de lo que tenes en memoria buscando los nuevos registros cuando vas por el 4500 por ejemplo(de esta forma te evitas el progress indicator cuando vas a cargar nuevos registros).

Comment: si que hay bastantes tipos de filtros y búsquedas, solo que pues que le dio por quitar el limite XD, gracias por tus consejos.

Comment: Luego tenes que aplicar el mismo principio cuando vas para arriba en caso de lo que tengas que mostrar ya no este en memoria.